# Cakephp default URL routing

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am having an user registration function with 3 types of account, namely typeA, typeB and typeC. Now I am having 3 URLs users/addTypeA, users/addTypeB and users/addTypeC. I want to make it more like a RESTful way, i.e. users/add/typeA, users/add/typeB, users/add/typeC. I believe I can use the default routing in cakephp to perform this but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I would use admin routing to solve this one, so in Config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/users/add/:action', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => ':action','add' => true));
```

Set up the admin routing in Config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('add'));
```

Then in your UsersController.php:

```
public function add_TypeA()
{

}

public function add_TypeB() 
{

}

public function add_TypeC()
{

}
```

This should give you the users/add/typeA routing you need